# Under whatsmyipaddress from a GCP instance, why is my ip not showing my external ip?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I download via proxy curl --proxy myGCPInstance https://whatsmyipaddress.com and it shows 172.241.89.134 which is not the 'static' external ip I added to my compute engine instance.  I am very confused by this.  Why is the wrong ip showing up?

ie. Why is external ip I connect to != external ip the whole world sees when we connect to 3rd party services?

I didn't want to setup a whole VPN/NAT deal just to have a single ip address that we can whitelist with 3rd party providers that have very tight security.  I mean it's good they prevent china ips, etc. by whitelisting customers, but trying to find a way to talk to them from google.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: What is the proxy for? Why not just fetch it directly from your instance?

Comment: We are trying to hit a service that requires we whitelist the ip address but the ip address seen outside google != external ip we set on the compute engine box.  While when we connect to compute engine, we use the external ip, why is it the external ip is not seen by the rest of the world when we connect to them?

Comment: OK, but why aren't you testing from your instance?

Comment: It sounds like your proxy is configured to add an X-Forwarded-For header with your internal address and that this is being picked up.  You should be able to suppress this behaviour in the proxy.